# Set Run on Behalf of for NotesAgent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is there a way to set "run on behalf of" in NotesAgent?

I tried solution with NotesNoteCollection

```
  Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
  Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
  Call nc.SelectAllCodeElements(True)
  nc.SelectAgents = true
  Call nc.BuildCollection
```

Then I loop nc and find my agent and set item $OnBehalfOf

```
call agentNote.replaceitemvalue("$OnBehalfOf", "username")
call agentNote.save(true, false)
```

That breaks on 'Save', it says it's not allowed to save agent.

I have also checked C API and have not found anything that can help me (but I could miss something)

Comment: Is your code running with Designer rights to the database containing the agent note that you are trying to save? I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I would think that would be a huge security hole.

Comment: @richardSchwartz yes, user who run that has Manager access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all -as mentioned in the comment by Richard- you need Designer- Access to the database to be able to change an agent like that as you directly modify a design element instead of using the interface (that somehow circumvents this for editing agents).

Second: Whenever you modify an agent via its underlying NotesDocument, you destroy the signature on the design- element: Even when saving works the agent will be broken and not run again.

So you need to add an `agentNote.Sign()` before your `agentNote.Save(...)` otherwise the agent will not be able to run.

And of course the person who executes this code needs the appropriate server right (Serverdocument - Security - Sign agents to run on behalf of someone else), otherwise the agent will not run.

Comment: Thanks, i will give a try and get back.